# How to view individual screen pixels on a web page

Tags: web, google-chrome-devtools

Anyone know of a convenient way to zoom in and look at individual pixels on a web page without scaling the page ?

I want to be able to see a representation of the individual pixels as rendered at 100% but with the naked eye - as you can in various drawing/paint programs.

Ideally I'd like to be able to do this from chrome developer tools but there doesn't seem to be a way.

Chrome zooming doesn't do it ; it scales the image eg. so a 4 pixel square becomes 9 pixels, 16 pixels etc.

Windows magnifier doesn't do it - it also scales the image not the pixels (though differently to the chrome zoom ; you end up with blurring).

Comment: Windows magnifier in "Lens" or "Docked" mode should do the trick. Otherwise look for an external utility as there are no additional methods in Chrome except for a laborious workaround of clicking a color in the Styles panel of Element inspector to invoke eyedropper in zoom mode.

Comment: @wOxxOm no, the magnifier's no use... but that laborious workaround got me what I needed for now - cheers ! Shame it's not more accessible and has such a small viewing window.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716775/how-to-use-color-picker-eye-dropper
This might be what you are looking for.