# Extracting javascript/framework and/or css style of underlying dashboard

Tags: javascript, plotly-dash, dashboard

I would like to know how I can extract the framework of a specific dashboard on a specific site: https://tradytics.com/overall-market. I like their UI very much, especially the sidebar and the theme in general. I would like to know how to recreate this, but since I have no working knowledge in javascript I don't know how to go about this. I know about the chrome developer console which gives me quite some information on the structure already, but I really want to extract it as some theme or transfer this to dash (in python) manually. How do I go about this?

Comment: I don't think there's a quick fix to do what you want to do. You can save the web page and try to adapt the stylesheets and scripts to your app, but I think this will be very difficult to work with. Since you're probably not going to understand what most styles and scripts are doing and there is a lot of code to go through. So I would start from scratch and try to recreate components and styles by inspecting the page, looking through the sources tab or the page source code view-source:https://tradytics.com/overall-market.

Comment: That page uses [chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/) and [d3](https://d3js.org/) for charts. Chrome also has an eyedropper tool if you can't find the color styles https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716775/how-to-use-color-picker-eye-dropper.